# How to execute Python Script through Informatica Cloud

Tags: informatica-cloud

I have a python script that I need to execute and automate via IICS. The output of the script is a csv file. This output should be loaded to the Target. How can I achieve this via Informatica cloud. Please help with some info and documentations to the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1. You can create an executable(using py2exe or some tool) from your py script. Then put that file in Informatica cloud agent server. Then you can call it using shell command. Please note, you do not need to install python or any packages.
2. You can also put the .py file in agent server and run it using shell like $PYTHON_HOME/python your_script.py You need to make sure py version is compatible and you have all packages installed in agent server.

You can refer to the below screenshot for how to setup shell command. Then you can run it as part of some workflow. Schedule it if needed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnDOV.png